# Android Studio Unable to create MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a music player for android just to learn something new and I am getting an error ont the MediaPlayer: **E/MediaPlayerNative: Unable to create media player**

> ```
> **E/MediaPlayerNative: Unable to create media player**
> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
> ```

If I need to add more just let me know if it helps.

Where I am getting the error:

```
    @Override
    public void onChanged(int pos) {
        if(songPlayer.isPlaying()){
            songPlayer.pause();
            songPlayer.reset();
        }

        songPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            //GETTING THE ERROR HERE
                            songPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), songList.get(pos).getSongFile());
                            songPlayer.prepare();
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to play the track", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

        songPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                int getTotalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

                //Convert song duration into the correct format
                String duration = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(getTotalDuration))),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(getTotalDuration))),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(getTotalDuration)))));

                endTime.setText(duration);
                isPlaying = true;

                mediaPlayer.start();

                songBar.setMax(getTotalDuration);

                playPauseImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            }
        });
    }
```